# BeanCreationException IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a little lost with this - below is my code...when I run it via IntelliJ debug mode, my Spring app fails to initialize with the following error...

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportController' defined in file [my_code_directory/ic/cybs/target/classes/com/ic/cybs/controller/ReportController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ic.cybs.controller.ReportController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am not sure why the Constructor is throwing an exception, the error is being thrown by this line in ReportController.java

```
private Properties mProp = Configuration.getMDetails();
```

**ReportController.java**

```
package com.ic.cybs.controller;

import com.cybs.authsdk.core.ConfigException;
import com.cybs.authsdk.core.MercConfig;
import com.ic.cybs.config.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Properties;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/cybs")
public class ReportController {
    // constructor
    public ReportController() throws ConfigException { }

    // private
    private Properties mProp = Configuration.getMDetails();
    private MercConfig mercConfig = new MercConfig(mProp);

    // public
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getIndex() {
        return String.format("%s", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Configuration.java**

```
package com.ic.cybs.config;

import java.util.Properties;

public class Configuration {
    // constructor

    // private

    // public
    public static Properties getMDetails() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        // HTTP_Signature = http_signature
        properties.setProperty("authenticationType", "http_signature");
        properties.setProperty("mID", System.getenv("M_ID"));
        properties.setProperty("runEnvironment", System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT"));
        properties.setProperty("requestJsonPath", "src/main/resources/request.json");

        // HTTP Parameters
        properties.setProperty("mKeyId", System.getenv("KEY_ID"));
        properties.setProperty("mSecretKey", System.getenv("SECRET_KEY"));

        // Logging to be enabled or not.
        properties.setProperty("enableLog", "true");
        // Log directory Path
        properties.setProperty("logDirectory", "log");
        properties.setProperty("logFilename", "cybs");
        // Log file size in KB
        properties.setProperty("logMaximumSize", "5M");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why I am getting this error...
Also please note that "Properties getMDetails()" is a public static method, therefore an actual constructor is not needed...

Below is the **complete stack trace...**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:56711,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:/Users/me/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.1/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/me/_code/ic/cybs/target/classes:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.11.2/log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.26/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.4/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/snakeyaml-1.24.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-actuator-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.9/jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.0.M3/spring-context-5.2.0.M3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.9/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.1.5/micrometer-core-1.1.5.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.9/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.9/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.9/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.21.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.2.0.M4/spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.0.M4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.1/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.17.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.0.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.0/classmate-1.5.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.0.M3/spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.0.M3/spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.2.0.M3/spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.2.0.M3/spring-aop-5.2.0.M3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.2.0.M3/spring-expression-5.2.0.M3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.8/lombok-1.18.8.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.M3/spring-core-5.2.0.M3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.0.M3/spring-jcl-5.2.0.M3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/cybs/AuthenticationSdk/0.0.5/AuthenticationSdk-0.0.5.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.45/bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/4.22/nimbus-jose-jwt-4.22.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0-1/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/net/minidev/asm/1.0.2/asm-1.0.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-1.2-api/2.11.2/log4j-1.2-api-2.11.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/1.0.9/json-smart-1.0.9.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/vertx/vertx-core/3.5.3/vertx-core-3.5.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.36.Final/netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.36.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.36.Final/netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.36.Final/netty-handler-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.36.Final/netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler-proxy/4.1.36.Final/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-socks/4.1.36.Final/netty-codec-socks-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.36.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http2/4.1.36.Final/netty-codec-http2-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.36.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver-dns/4.1.36.Final/netty-resolver-dns-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-dns/4.1.36.Final/netty-codec-dns-4.1.36.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.9/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.ic.cybs.cybsApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56711', transport: 'socket'
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.2.0.M4)

2019-07-21 13:34:10.051  INFO 68613 --- [           main] c.i.cybs.cybsApplication   : Starting cybsApplication on Didiers-MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 68613 (/Users/me/_code/ic/cybs/target/classes started by me in /Users/me/_code/ic/cybs)
2019-07-21 13:34:10.054  INFO 68613 --- [           main] c.i.cybs.cybsApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-07-21 13:34:11.183  INFO 68613 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-07-21 13:34:11.190  INFO 68613 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-07-21 13:34:11.191  INFO 68613 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-07-21 13:34:11.256  INFO 68613 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-07-21 13:34:11.256  INFO 68613 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1145 ms
2019-07-21 13:34:11.462  WARN 68613 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportController' defined in file [/Users/me/_code/ic/cybs/target/classes/com/ic/cybs/controller/ReportController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ic.cybs.controller.ReportController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2019-07-21 13:34:11.465  INFO 68613 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-07-21 13:34:11.480  INFO 68613 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-21 13:34:11.487 ERROR 68613 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportController' defined in file [/Users/me/_code/ic/cybs/target/classes/com/ic/cybs/controller/ReportController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ic.cybs.controller.ReportController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:870) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:748) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1227) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1216) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at com.ic.cybs.cybsApplication.main(cybsApplication.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ic.cybs.controller.ReportController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.put(Properties.java:1316) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at com.ic.cybs.config.Configuration.getMerchantDetails(Configuration.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ic.cybs.controller.ReportController.<init>(ReportController.java:90) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56711', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you add complete stack trace

Comment: You get a NPE. See the stacktrace.

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: Put a breakpoint.  My guess is that the properties you assume are coming back are null.

Comment: Read your stacktrace carefully. `at com.ic.cybs.config.Configuration.getMerchantDetails(Configuration.java:86) ~[classes/:na]` tells NPE is throwed not from getMDetails() as you think.

Comment: The stack trace tells you that, at line 86 of Configuration.java, you're trying to put a null value into Properties. So, find the line 86, and wonder why the value is null and what you should do about it.

Comment: LOL - I completely missed that line...tired eyes...thanks guys...
I was calling environmental variables but IntelliJ had zero idea where to get the values...